# Replacing std::greater and others

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading, functor

In my C++ code I wrote two functors that I could use them as arguments to functions. like this:

```
template<class T>
class MyGreater{
public:
    bool operator()(const T &value1, const T &value2) {
            return value1 > value2;
    }
};

template<class T>
class MyEquall{
public:
    bool operator()(const T &value1, const T &value2) {
            return value1 == value2;
    }
};
```

But now I am looking to write like 4 other to cover all of these: `<,<=,>,>=,==,!=` does that mean I need to write 4 different classes for everyone?

**Important Note: I know I can use std::Greater and so on, but my professor won't allow this and told us to write our own code.**

**I'm working with C++11 and want to stick with functors**

Comment: that doesn't sound efficient :-)

Comment: That's why C++20 introduced `operator<=>`, that replaces four of them.

Comment: I don't know what are those strange requirements, are all professors like this? I mean it's few lines of code why to write them

Comment: and @SamVarshavchik from your experience could you recommend a better name rather than using MyGreater and so on?

Comment: You should definitely just call it `greater`. But put it in your own namespace, so it becomes `my::greater`, and so on.

Comment: Based on prior questions posted on stackoverflow.com from others who find themselves in similar settings, and relate the information they get from their instructors, I must estimate that 75% of college-level C++ instructors are grossly incompetent and are not qualified to teach C++. That, of course, doesn't help the students, so the only advice I have to offer is to figure out what the instructors want, hand in your assignments as expected, but do not rely on them to learn C++, if you are planning on a career as a C++ developer; but mostly learn how to write quality C++ code on your own.

Comment: We can't comment about all professors. Yes it seems like a pointless exercise. But perhaps your professor is just trying to teach about writing functors? Toy examples are usually good candidates to demonstrate a point. Plus, after writing boiler-plate one becomes appreciative when the standard library offers a solution.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ok hear this: in c we learnt how to write an array of chars very well but in C++ he doesn't want us to use string at all only char*

Comment: @smith - Well, I was trying to be generous with your prof's potential motive. Sadly it's also possible the professor is adhering to a very outdated way of teach C++. It's a point of vigorous debate. If you are interested, there's a talk I really like that touches on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk

Answer (score 1):

If your professor doesn't disallow the use of the preprocessor, you can spare yourself some tedious boilerplate:

```
#define DEFINE_MY_GENERIC_OP(CLASS_NAME, OP)                  \
template<class T>                                             \
class CLASS_NAME{                                             \
public:                                                       \
    bool operator()(const T &value1, const T &value2) const { \
            return value1 OP value2;                          \
    }                                                         \
}
```

Then use it like this

```
DEFINE_MY_GENERIC_OP(MyGreater, >);
DEFINE_MY_GENERIC_OP(MyEquall, ==);
// etc
```

I wouldn't *normally* recommend the preprocessor, but since you are faced with a silly requirement that forces you to tediously repeat the same tokens, it seems somewhat appropriate.

If this approach is prohibited as well, then you must spell each operator out unfortunately.

Comment: I know it's not your bug, but the operator should be `const` (or perhaps even `static`?).

Comment: @TonyDelroy - `operator()` must be a non-static member

Comment: true, but the functionality could be provided in a named function that was `static`, some people prefer that when the function doesn't depend on any class data members - just depends on how much the caller cares about the notation they have to use.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I forgot to see that he thinks preprocessor is ALWAYS a bad code

Answer (score 0):

“That doesn’t sound efficient”: that’s an entirely wrong impression. As far as the code you’d be writing, it’s perhaps the simplest to write, and since you’re using C++11 you don’t need the boilerplate at all. Just the saucy bits :)

```
using MyGreater = decltype([](auto &&l, auto &&r){ return l > r; });
```

You need another 5 lines like the above. And that’s all. It’s perhaps the most efficient and straightforward thing you’ll ever be doing in C++ - just look at how simple it is compared to all the other code you write! It will need unit tests of course since such trivial code has the highest likelihood of being wrong - it’s so simple that we pay it the least attention. I recently worked on some smart pointer code where all the simple bits were half-broken until I wrote the equally simple unit tests for it. The hard parts worked since they were hard to write and I paid them lots of attention.

If you were allowed to use C++20, you’d only need the UFO/spaceship operator:

```
using SpaceCowboys  = decltype([](auto &&l, auto &&r){ return l <=> r; });
```

Finally: The professor did not ask you to do it to be efficient, but to see how it’s done (in at least one way out of many). The point of the exercise wasn’t to avoid boilerplate. It was for you to be forced at least once in your life thus far to write such boilerplate to get awareness of what’s going on under the hood. *The suggestions to tuck it away in a macro or other such hacks completely miss the point, since the code is unnecessary anyway - was it not a school project, you’d be using other ways to achieve it, without writing any code at all - but that would hide what’s going on.* It could be of course argued what pedagogical utility all this had - there’s always someone who could suggest any teacher how to use the students’ instruction time better. But I don’t see anything terribly misguided about such an exercise. Be thankful you’re not asked to play all modes of all major scales for 6 months straight for an hour a day :)

Comment: I don't see much point going through the type of the lambda, just to recreate an object of that type later, but ok.

Comment: I wrote the exact equivalent, and furthermore you don’t always need to create an instance yourself. Sometimes it’s just a template argument, say to std::map. You don’t create an instance then, and an instance wouldn’t help - you’d be just extracting its type. But other times you want an object. So it’s a wash I guess.

Comment: C++11 doesn't allow lambdas in unevaluated operands. Nor does it allow default initializing lambdas (which *using* the functor will require). Those are C++20 features.